# How to handle soap fault in javascript

Tags: javascript, web-services, httprequest

Hi I am using javascript to call web services which are in .net.I used http request to call web services,I want to handle the soap fault in javascript,how to that??

Answer (score 0):

You can use jQuery Soap, a plugin for communicating with a web service using SOAP

"This script uses $.ajax to send a SOAP:Envelope. It can take XML DOM, XML string or JSON as input and the response can be returned as either XML DOM, XML string or JSON too."

I haven't tried this but it seems robust and easy to get started with.

Example:

```
$.soap({
    url: 'http://my.server.com/soapservices/',
    method: 'helloWorld',

data: {
    name: 'Remy Blom',
    msg: 'Hi!'
},

success: function (soapResponse) {
    // do stuff with soapResponse
    // if you want to have the response as JSON use soapResponse.toJSON();
    // or soapResponse.toString() to get XML string
    // or soapResponse.toXML() to get XML DOM
},
error: function (SOAPResponse) {
    // show error
}
});
```

source: https://github.com/doedje/jquery.soap